# Almost got it from V2 to V5 [mutable function???]

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

```
//@version=2
strategy("Heikin MA Trend ", shorttitle="HA Trend", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, initial_capital=1000, currency=currency.USD)


res1 = input(title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="D")
myma = input(40,"MA Period")
Length = input(15, minval=1)
Price = input(hlc3)
peace = abs(Price - Price[1])
Fastend = input(2.5,step=.5)
Slowend = input(200)
nfastend = 2/(Fastend + 1)
nslowend = 2/(Slowend + 1)
nsignal = abs(Price - Price[Length])
nnoise = sum(peace, Length)
nefratio = iff(nnoise != 0, nsignal / nnoise, 0)
nsmooth = pow(nefratio * (nfastend - nslowend) + nslowend, 2) 
nAMA = nz(nAMA[1]) + nsmooth * (Price - nz(nAMA[1]))
trend = heikinashi(tickerid)
trend_close = security(trend, period, nAMA)
ltrend_close = security(trend, res1, hlc3)
fma = ema(ltrend_close,1)
sma = ema(trend_close,myma)



/////// Testing Window //////
FromMonth = input(defval=1, title='From Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
FromDay = input(defval=1, title='From Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
FromYear = input(defval=2021, title='From Year', minval=1972)
ToMonth = input(defval=1, title='To Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
ToDay = input(defval=1, title='To Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
ToYear = input(defval=2075, title='To Year', minval=2017)

start = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)  // backtest start window
finish = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)  // backtest finish window
startTimeOk() =>  // create function "within window of time" if statement true
    time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false
    
    
plot(fma,title="MA",color=orange,linewidth=2,style=line)
plot(sma,title="SMA",color=red,linewidth=2,style=line)



golong = crossover(fma,sma) and startTimeOk()
goshort = crossunder(fma,sma) and startTimeOk()


strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long,when = golong)
strategy.entry("Sell",strategy.short,when = goshort)
```

ABOVE IS THE ORIGINAL CODE

BELOW IS MY UPDATED PROBLEM ALMOST FINISHED

```
//@version=5
strategy("Heikin MA Trend ", shorttitle="HA Trend", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, initial_capital=1000, currency=currency.USD)


res1 = input.timeframe(title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame", defval="D")
myma = input(40,"MA Period")
Length = input.int(15, minval=1)
Price = input(hlc3)
peace = math.abs(Price - Price[1])
Fastend = input.float(2.5,step=.5)
Slowend = input(200)
nfastend = 2/(Fastend + 1)
nslowend = 2/(Slowend + 1)
nsignal = math.abs(Price - Price[Length])
nnoise = math.sum(peace, Length)
nefratio = nnoise != 0 ? nsignal / nnoise : 0
nsmooth = math.pow(nefratio * (nfastend - nslowend) + nslowend, 2) 
nAMA = 0.0
nAMA := nz(nAMA[1]) + nsmooth * (Price - nz(nAMA[1]))
nAMA2 = nAMA == 0 ? open : nAMA
trend = ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
trend_close = request.security(trend, timeframe.period, nAMA2)
ltrend_close = request.security(trend, res1, hlc3)
fma = ta.ema(ltrend_close,1)
sma = ta.ema(trend_close,myma)



/////// Testing Window //////
FromMonth = input.int(defval=1, title='From Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
FromDay = input.int(defval=1, title='From Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
FromYear = input.int(defval=2022, title='From Year', minval=1972)
ToMonth = input.int(defval=1, title='To Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
ToDay = input.int(defval=1, title='To Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
ToYear = input.int(defval=2025, title='To Year', minval=2017)

start = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)  // backtest start window
finish = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)  // backtest finish window
startTimeOk() =>  // create function "within window of time" if statement true
    time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false
    
    
plot(fma,title="MA",color=color.white,linewidth=2,style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(sma,title="SMA",color=color.red,linewidth=2,style=plot.style_linebr)


golong = ta.crossover(fma,sma) and startTimeOk()
goshort = ta.crossunder(fma,sma) and startTimeOk()


strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long,when = golong)
strategy.entry("Sell",strategy.short,when = goshort)
```

It states --Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 22: Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the request.security function.--
Which is this line
trend_close = request.security(trend, timeframe.period, nAMA2)
I am at a loss on how to make it work???

Answer (score 0):

You need to move every calculation steps related to `nAMA` to a function and use this function as `expression` argument in `security()`.

Something like this:

```
f_get_nAMA() =>
    nfastend = 2/(Fastend + 1)
    nslowend = 2/(Slowend + 1)
    nsignal = math.abs(Price - Price[Length])
    nnoise = math.sum(peace, Length)
    nefratio = nnoise != 0 ? nsignal / nnoise : 0
    nsmooth = math.pow(nefratio * (nfastend - nslowend) + nslowend, 2) 
    nAMA = 0.0
    nAMA := nz(nAMA[1]) + nsmooth * (Price - nz(nAMA[1]))
    nAMA2 = nAMA == 0 ? open : nAMA

trend_close = request.security(trend, timeframe.period, f_get_nAMA())
```